# Linear Search through a list

Tags: python, algorithm

```
def linear_search(list, target):
    """Returns the index position of the target if found, else return None"""
    for i in range(0,len(list)):
        if list[i] == target:
            return i
        return None

def verify(index):
    if index is not None:
        print("Target found at index: ", index)
    else:
        print("Target not found in list")
        
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]


result = linear_search(numbers, 12)
verify(result)

result = linear_search(numbers, 6)
verify(result)
```

The console keeps printing "Target not found in list" Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Which programming language do you use?

Comment: What programming language are you using? Please [edit] your question and add it to tags, so that people can find it.

Comment: Im using Python 3.10. I found the problem it was the return None statement it was indented wrong

Comment: I very strongly recommend never naming any variable `list` or any other name from that list: [python builtins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html). This can be the cause of unforeseen problems. (Also note that "list" appears in orange in your question, whereas "target" appears in white)

Answer (score 0):

The loop returns immediately if the first element does not match, because the `return None` is inside the loop. Fix up the indentation to move it out of the loop instead:

```
def linear_search(list, target):
    """Returns the index position of the target if found, else return None"""
    for i in range(0,len(list)):
        if list[i] == target:
            return i
    return None
```

By the way, you can also just do `numbers.index(6)` to get the same result.